# Filtering the self-join query if both rows have same values in the columns and if the first five characters are same

Tags: sql, database, join, sql-server-2012

I executed the following query using self-join

```
SELECT 
    a.Product_ID , b.Parent_Product_ID, b.Product_Name 
    FROM Product a, Product b
    where a.Product_ID = b.Parent_Product_ID
```

This is the result

```
Product_ID  Parent_Product_ID Prodcut_Name 
311        311             Trench
353        353             Blended wool
353        353             Blended wool polyester
355        355             Faux fur
357        357             Quilted 
358        358            Jackets-Polyester
359        359            Jackets-Wool
```

I am trying to filter above result by

a)  Product_ID = Parent_Prodcut_ID if both rows have same values in the columns.
Here the result should be

```
353        353             Blended wool
353        353             Blended wool polyester
```

b)   If the first five characters in Product_name are same, here the result should be

```
353        353             Blended wool
353        353             Blended wool polyester
358        358            Jackets-Polyester
359        359            Jackets-Wool
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks I am tagging now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add these conditions to the `on` clause (oh, your query should have that too):

```
SELECT a.Product_ID , b.Parent_Product_ID, b.Product_Name 
FROM Product a JOIN
     Product b
     ON a.Product_ID = b.Parent_Product_ID AND
        a.product_name = b.product_name;
```

And for the second:

```
SELECT a.Product_ID , b.Parent_Product_ID, b.Product_Name 
FROM Product a JOIN
     Product b
     ON a.Product_ID = b.Parent_Product_ID AND
        LEFT(a.product_name, 5) = LEFT(b.product_name, 5);
```

If your database doesn't have a `LEFT()` function, use `SUBSTR()`/`SUBSTRING()` instead.